# How to set OTP through E-mail/SMS in my Amazon server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sns, one-time-password

I have to set One Time Password in my application. That OTP through E-mail/SMS, should generate from my server that is in Amazon. I searched for some of their services like Amazon SNS and SES. Could you please tell me which one is  best and how to use/implement it in my server?

I have generated OTP. Now I need to pass this OTP to users via Email. Beside Amazon SNS/SES,Is there any options to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little open ended. I can understand ( or will assume ) that there you have a mechanism to handle, generate and manage the OTP process; you are looking for a delivery mechanism to send OTP to your clients.

SNS - Simple Notification Service offloads your over head to scale the process of pub-sub system. You can have SNS endpoint and call an API to send a piece of information. On the other side of the SNS - you can have several channels [ SES, SMS, SQS, Push Notification, HTTP / HTTPS endpoint ] which would listen to the SNS.

There are services like Twilio which would just send and / or call you to tell about the OTP; which can triggered from / by your system.

It purely depends on your use case, target users.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use an API like [Nexmo Verify API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify).

This API handles the complete end-to-end functionality

1. One Time Password (OTP) generation
2. Deliver the generated OTP over SMS or Voice (incase if the provided number is not reachable or if its a landline)
3. Verification of the code

The best part is they charge only on a successful verification.

This could simplify the logic on your application and remove the dependency on SNS.